# Mysql data displaying multiple rows instead of one row

Tags: mysql

[image]

I would like to know how to display the data above into one row based on the field value i did a case select but it's coming up as the following image

```
(SELECT lead_id,
 case lead_id
 case field_number when 1  then value  end as firstname

 case field_number when 1 then value end as firstname,
 case field_number when 2 then value end as lastname,
 case field_number when 10 then value end as email,
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to do it with conditional aggregation (meaning you are missing a group by clause an a max/min function) :

```
SELECT lead_id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 1 then value end) as firstname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 2 then value end) as lastname,
       MAX(CASE WHEN field_number = 10 then value end) as email
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY lead_id
```

Comment: Worth noting that this table layout goes against the grain entirely.

Comment: Thanks sagi this was very useful i knew i was missing something about the lead id.

Comment: BTW i did not create this database nor the table and you right Barry TheHatchet terrible disign.

Comment: No problem @MasterPage :)